# How can I create a function that pushes elements into an array?

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to figure out why this function isn't pushing anything to the array I defined. When I print_r $location_matches it is empty.

```
$id = get_the_ID();
$location_matches = array();

function find_location_meta($location_id, $product_id, $location_matches_arr) {
    $meta_info = get_post_meta($location_id);
    $working_with = unserialize($meta_info[locations_products_carried][0]);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($working_with); $i++) {
        if ( $working_with[$i][locations_products][0] == $product_id ) {
            array_push($location_matches_arr, $working_with[$i]);
        }
    }
}

find_location_meta(94, $id, $location_matches);
```

Comment: You need to either return your array or pass it by reference.

Comment: $working_with = unserialize($meta_info[locations_products_carried][0]); - locations_products_carried is either a variable - then you need the $ sign, or it's a string then you need quotes, if I think right. Try "print_r"-ing the $meta_info and / or $working_with - I suggest you go step by step. Check whether $working_with has any elements BEFORE you iterate on it, and there's a problem with locations_products (it's a variable or a string!). And is 94 a correct $location_id for sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a passage by reference if you would like to change a variable that way so :

```
$id = get_the_ID();
$location_matches = array();

function find_location_meta($location_id, $product_id, &$location_matches_arr) {
    $meta_info = get_post_meta($location_id);
    $working_with = unserialize($meta_info[locations_products_carried][0]);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($working_with); $i++) {
        if ( $working_with[$i][locations_products][0] == $product_id ) {
            array_push($location_matches_arr, $working_with[$i]);
        }
    }
}

find_location_meta(94, $id, $location_matches);
```

You would notice that I added `&` in the declaration of the function so it could point to that exact variable and change it's content.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you!